# Radio Group and radio buttons

Tags: android

I need to implement a multiple choice question. I have to add radio buttons and text view for multiple choice. I need to implement it dynamically corresponding to the number of choices. Can someone help me

```
for (Answer answer : answers) {
    LinearLayout linearLayoutRw2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayoutRw2
            .setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(
            ShowQuestionsActivity.this);
    linearLayoutRw2.addView(radioGroup);

    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(ShowQuestionsActivity.this);
    radioGroup.addView(rb);

    TextView ansText = new TextView(ShowQuestionsActivity.this);
    ansText.setText(Html.fromHtml(answer.getAnswerText()));
    linearLayoutRw2.addView(ansText);

    linearLayoutShowQues.addView(linearLayoutRw2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this,

First create a `ListView` dynamically.

```
    ListView choicelist = new ListView(this);
    choicelist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    choicelist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                   android.R.id.text1, your_answer_list));
    choicelist.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(0x0));
    choicelist.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    choicelist.setCacheColorHint(0);
    choicelist.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
```

**And Finally add this List to your Layout**

```
linearLayoutShowQues.addView(choicelist);
```

For Customisation you can use Custom Adapter.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: List<Answer> answers = question.getAnswers();
   if (answers != null && answers.size() > 0) {

    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(
      MNActivity.this);
    int num = answers.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
     final RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(
       MN.this);
     final Answer ans = answers.get(i);
     rb.setText(Html.fromHtml(ans.getAnswerText()));
     radioGroup.addView(rb);
    }
    linearLayout.addView(radioGroup);